# Installing Facebook comment plug in without loosing all previous wordpress comments?

Tags: plugins, comments, facebook

I'm trying to install Facebook comments onto a word press blog, but I do not want to loose all the previous comments. I'm curious if anyone has any ideas how to do this. I've looked at a lot of the various plugins, and haven't been able to find a good solution.

I would like to find a way for the Facebook comment system to be the default comment system, and if someone doesn't have Facebook (or doesn't want to use it) they can use the default wordpress comment system (unless something different exists.) Another option is to use the default wordpress plug in on all previous posts, and moving forward use just the Facebook plug in.  I just don't want it to look like all previous posts have no comments when they actually do, if that makes sense.

I'm open to any ideas that you have. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From all I could research on this, there's just no way to "merge" existing WP comments onto the Facebook Plugin. So my solution for this problem with a client was to style wordpress comments exactly like fb comments, except that they always appear below all other fb comments.

Then, by default, i leave the fb comment form loaded on the single page, and at the bottom of everything i have this "don't use facebook? comment here" button, calling WordPress' default popup comments window.

This way you can still have both functionalities and still privilege fb comments.

**EDIT:**

I didn't realize you were talking about plugins in general, and not about the actual [FB Comments App](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/comments/). My solution was to install it by hand, on the actual `comments.php` instead of looking for a plugin. It turned out to be easier than to find a plugin that would do it exactly as i wanted.

Answer (score 1):

You can install easily new facebook plugin without loosing previous . If you changed the path of post then your like and comment will be reset.

So do not  change path and uninstall previous and install new.

Answer (score 0):

What Facebook Connect plugins have you been looking at in particular?  Do they mention that you will lose your previous comments if you install them?  Your best bet is finding a plugin that sounds good to you, and then reading up on that one in particular, or even contacting the developer.

I think your first step should be to back up your site, including both site files and MySQL Databases just incase you do end up losing the comments.

I apologize that this isn't a concrete answer, but hopefully it will point you in the right direction.

Comment: What I mean by "loose" them, is that if you install the Facebook comment plug ins (any that I've found) your comment box will be replaced with the Facebook one. And so someone looking at an old post will see no comments. (The other way of doing it is to leave the wordpress comment box up with the Facebook one..but it looks messy. I wish there was a way to merge the two.

Answer (score 0):

I think the only way to merge the comments is by using third party comment systems like [Livefyre](http://www.livefyre.com/), [Disqus](http://disqus.com/welcome/), and [Intense Debate](http://intensedebate.com/); but not [Facebook's comments](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/comments/).

**Alternatively** you can just show old comments, if available, above the Facebook comments, and show just the Facebook comments if nothing else is available.